# Stop a loop inside a suscriber Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, loops

I was wondering what is the best way to stop a while loop depending on the results of the suscriber. The function is asynchronous so `break` is not valid. I tried the following way but it never updates `this.output = false` so the loop is infinite.

```
getTesting(){
    while ( this.output == true ){      
      this.dataService.getThings().subscribe(res=> {
        if(res.length == 10){
          ...
          this.output = true
        }
        else{
          this.output = false
        }        
      })
    }
  }
```

Comment: Here you are creating as many subscriptions as there are iterations of the loop. Do you need to keep making requests to a server until a certain response length is reached?

Comment: Yes, I need to make these requests

Comment: `while(true) { /** just about ANYTHING **/ }` does nothing but block the main UI thread. Life for the user will suck.

Comment: what do you want to do? Stopping the loop will not stop the subscription, if it has already been started. You have to cancel (= unsubscribe) the subscription, here: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/the-best-way-to-unsubscribe-rxjs-observable-in-the-angular-applications-d8f9aa42f6a0